# Change UINavigationBar alpha to 0.5, then back home and return to app. the navigationBar alpha change to 1 automatic

Tags: ios, objective-c

first

[image]

second

[image]

Change UINavigationBar alpha to 0.5, then back home and return to app. the navigationBar alpha change to 1 automatic  I want to Know how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "then back home"?

Comment: Write your code in viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: I has set translucent = yes

Comment: but it will change to 1 automic

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    }

Comment: And  applicationWillEnterForeground   not call viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the navigationBar color with alpha value 0.5?
is this your code to set alpha ?

`[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWith RGBA]`